# Avoid wordpress permalink redirect

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I have a bit of an issue when trying to edit a wordpress permalink for a post. In the post edit page, I can simply edit the link to the post, to make it look prettier.

[image: editing a permalink]

That works fine. However, across the whole website, when I hover over a link to the post, I can see when I inspect it that it is still pointing to an ugly-formatted url, which gets redirected afterwards.

[image: still pointing to the ugly url]

Is there a way to have the links to the posts across the whole website point to their pretty edited link, instead of the default ugly one? I have researched the wordpress doc and haven’t found a default function that does something close to what I want to do.

Any help is much appreciated,

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try once custom permalinks plugin

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried implementing the site permalink settings? Go to "Settings->Permalinks" and select the "Post name" option. Hope this works for you!

Comment: I have tried that, but the url is still getting re-written. When I hover over the link, it is still showing the ugly version :/

Comment: Did you edit your link after changing the permalink settings?

Comment: I don't believe so, but it's possible. If I did, what should I do?

Comment: Changing the settings should change the urls. I tried it and it works, perhaps your issues is coming from elsewhere.